# jqGrid setting filterToolbar value programmatically

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with code similar to following sample code:

```
jQuery("#list10").jqGrid({
    url:'MyServlateName?action=MyAction',
    datatype: "xml",
    mtype:"POST",
    ajaxSelectOptions: {type: "POST"},
    sortable: true,
    height: "100%",
    rowNum:4,
    width: 1000,
    emptyrecords: "No Records to display",
    colNames:['Contact No', 'Cust ID', 'Name'], 
    colModel:[
          {name:'CNO',index:'CNO', width:80,sortable:true},
          {name:'CUSTID',index:'CUSTID', width:60,sortable:true},
          {name:'CNAME',index:'CNAME', width:200,sortable:true, searchoptions:{ sopt:['cn']}},
    ],
    pager: '#pager10',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'CUSTID',
    shrinkToFit: false,
    toppager: true,
    sortorder: "asc"
}

}).navGrid('#pager10',{cloneToTop:true, edit:false,add:false,del:false,view:true,search: false, refresh:true},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {recreateForm: true,width:700,navkeys: [true,38,40]}
);
jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('bindKeys');
$("#list10").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true,searchOnEnter: false});
```

In filterToolbar I am putting CUSTID programmatically using following code:

```
document.getElementById("gs_CUSTID").value=CUST_ID_VAR_NAME;
```

It is showing the value in filterToolbar in CUSTID column but grid is not populated/searched according to the CUSTID I have put(NO SEARCH HAPPENS). If I do regular search using filterToolbar then it works fine.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the problem in different ways. For example you can trigger `change` event on `#gs_CUSTID` after setting the value in the control:

```
$("#gs_CUSTID").val("123");
$("#gs_CUSTID").trigger("change");
```

More better will be to set `datatype: "local"` initially in the grid. It will prevent loading of *unfiltered* data from `'MyServlateName?action=MyAction'` during creating the grid. After that you can change `datatype` to `"xml"` using `setGridParam`, set value in `#gs_CUSTID` and trigger the `change` event at the end.

```
$("#list10").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "xml"});
$("#gs_CUSTID").val("123");
$("#gs_CUSTID").trigger("change");
```

Instead of triggering `change` you can call `triggerToolbar` method manually (see [the part](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.custom.js#L491-L494) of jqGrid code):

```
$("#list10").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "xml"});
$("#gs_CUSTID").val("123");
$("#list10")[0].triggerToolbar();
```

Comment: I used the last approach from your answer. and its working fine. Thanks.